# Displaying given recommendations on LinkedIn profile

Tags: linkedin

The recommendations I've received on `LinkedIn` appear just fine. I've given a recommendation to a person I believe I friended in an “other” capacity. It shows up on their profile, but it is not displaying on mine.

How do I make sure the recommendation I wrote for someone else displays on my own profile?

**update**

I don't see a "Given" link in the top right of the Recommendation section on my profile.  All I see are "Ask to be Recommended" and "Manage".  When I click on "Manage", it brings me to the Recommendations page, which includes links for "Received" and "Given".  Under "Given", the given recommendation appears, with the option selected to "Display on my profile" to "connections."  However, nothing is displayed.  Is it possibly because I have not worked with this person, and friended them in an "other" capacity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recommendations that you write for other people appear:

- In the **Recommendations** section on your profile. You'll need to click the **Given** link in the top right of the Recommendation section to see them.
- In the Recommendations section on the recipient's profile, after they accept the recommendation.

To hide or display a recommendation that you gave:

- Go to your profile.
- Scroll to the **Recommendations** section and click the **Given** link.
- Scroll to the recommendation you want to hide or display.
- Under **Display on your profile to**, select **Your Connections, Everyone**, or **No One**.

**Note:** This only changes how the recommendation displays on your own profile. It won't hide it from the recipient's profile. You must remove your recommendation to prevent it from displaying on their profile.

For more information look at LinkedIn help center of [Hiding and Unhiding Your Recommendations](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/165/~/hiding-and-unhiding-your-recommendations).

**Update:**

When you click on `Profile` tab you simply enter in `edit profile` mode. So that time it does not show **Given** link. But if you click on `View profile as` (a tab near to you profile picture), It show how your profile looks to your connections, that time you can see the **Given** link. This confirms that the recommendation you have written is added on your profile and visible to your connections (or public, depends or your setting).

Hope this update will help you.

Comment: Thanks @serenesat.  I am updating my question to respond.

Comment: @WalrustheCat: Look at updated section of the answer.